# Git pulls updating Config file instead of ignoring

Tags: git, visual-studio, gitignore, git-pull

I have a config file inside my Git project directory (bad i know and changing it) and the file is part of my `.gitignore`

```
# User-specific files
*.suo
*.user
*.userosscache
*.sln.docstates
PATH/systemConfig.json
```

The file is not part of my Visual studio solution and whenever i do a git pull on other computers it overwrites the config file with the same data from my config file on my develop computer.

I've tried using this command but it seems to work half the time

`git update-index --assume-unchanged PATH/systemConfig.json`

Am i using gitignore incorrectly?

Eventually I will be moving the config files to the users home directory to avoid conflicts on git pulls.

Comment: If you ignore this file why would git overwrite it? Or maybe it was in your repo and **then** you have added it to `.gitignore`?

Comment: Well the file was probably part of the folder before i added the gitignore, but i did use `git rm --cached PATH/systemConfig.json`. I made a copy and copied it back into the folder after without any sucess.

Comment: Do `git clone` of your repo to some other location to be 100% sure which files are in repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git rm --cached PATH/systemConfig.json` is not enough: you have then to add and commit in order to record the deletion of that from from Git content.

Only then others will have their own config file left alone during a pull.

Comment: Ok so i followed this, committed after removing the file from being tracked, did a git pull followed by git push and now the files are never modified. Thanks!